# Modify destination port in TCP/IP headers of all outgoing packets

Tags: windows, ssh, dns, tcp

Used SSH Tunnel to route the traffic addressed to server1:port1 to server2:port2.

Now,the problem is that i want to redirect all TCP/IP packets from desktop addressed to server1:port1 to server2:port2.
using "hosts" file on windows, i mapped server1 ip as ipaddress of server2. [local DNS mapping]

http://server2:port2  //gives the desired page.
http://server1:port2  //gives the desired page as server1 ip is mapped as that of server2 ip.

Is it possible to rewrite the destination port of all TCP/IP packets addressed to some host?
[Transform destination port all TCP/IP packets with (destn ip as server1 and destn port as port1) to port2] 
This is required as there is no direct access to server1 from the working desktop.
I can't use the same port number on server2 as that of server1 as that port is already taken on server2.

Please share your comments on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use iptables to rewrite the destination port either on the desktop machine or on an intermediate router.

Comment: Thanks very much for pointing me to the right direction for this question. 
As iptables are not there on windows. used similar software "ipfilter1"